# Scale text size with CSS

Tags: css, scale

Is there any kind of property or a CSS solution that scales your text depending on the parent dimensions. So that text will not get out of content regardless of parent size ?

I have a div where I add my text. This div is dynamically shkrinked and when this is done the text is displayed outside the div.

Comment: Does using line-height not help you here?

Comment: Using `em`'s instead of `px` would be something that could help here if the element size is dependant on viewport size. You may also want to try adding different class with javascript to element after it is resized. In this new class you can define different font size.

Comment: Please try to explain your issue clearly. A sample code will help to understand clearly here.

Comment: if you don't mind using jquery, there's a nifty plugin for this called [TextFill](https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill)

Comment: That's excactly what I want but if it possible only with CSS!

Comment: I ran into an issue like this not too long ago, and unfortunately I wasn't able to find a CSS-only solution. I ended up using TextFill